# Read file by fscanf and after it's by fgets

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

given a file (`file.txt`) with the following content:

> 123 456
>   789 101

I don't understand why after that I read from the file the first line (by `fscanf`) it's not work to read the second line.

```
int main() {
    FILE* fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return 1;
    int n1, n2;
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &n1, &n2);
    char buffer[10]="";
    fgets(buffer, 10, fp);
    printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

What is the problem? (I tried to add `\n` in the format of fscanf and then it's works, but I don't understand why I must add `\n` to the format of `fscanf`?)

Comment: You basically can't intermix `fscanf` and `fgets` like this.  It never works

Comment: Either call `fgets` plus `sscanf` to read the first line, or use `fscanf` with `%s` or `%[^\n]` to read the second one.

Comment: "why I must add \n to the format of fscanf" you don't have to, but it is one way to cope with ill advised mix of using `fgets()` and `fscanf()`.  Recommend to use only one of those 2.

Comment: @SteveSummit Why not? if I will wirte `fscanf(fp, "%d %d\n", &n1, &n2);` it's will be correct.

Comment: @J.Roe `fscanf(fp, "%d %d\n"...` is not correct if the line after `123 456` is only white-space.  It is consumed by `fscanf(fp, "%d %d\n"...`

Comment: @J.Roe I was exaggerating slightly when I said it "never" works, but it remains a magnificently error-prone way of doing things.  As I said, I recommend not trying to intermix `*scanf` and `*gets`.  If you want to understand why adding `\n` to the format string seemed to fix it, see one of the several thousand related questions.  *Everybody* has this problem when they try to call `*gets` after `*scanf`.

Comment: @J.Roe Do not mix the use of `fgets()`, `fscanf()` until you know why code _should not mix_ them.  By that time one will understand how to use them properly together.   For know, consider never using `scanf()`, `fscanf()`.  `sscanf()` is OK.

Comment: @SteveSummit ok, thank you anyway.